# Designing Fluent interface methods

Tags: c#, .net, linq, generics, fluent-interface

I am trying to write a DSL

I have methods that return strings but if I want to combine the strings I need to use a + symbol but I would like to call the methods together but I'm unsure how to achieve it

I have methods at the moment such as

`MyStaticClass.Root() MyStaticClass.And() MyStaticClass.AnyInt()` which return strings

I would like to be able to do

`Root().And().AnyInt()` which result in a string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The methods should return a wrapper class.  The methods are also *instance methods* of the wrapper class.  Example:

```
class Fluent
{
     private string _value;
     public Fluent And()
     {
         this._value += "whatever";
         return this;
     }
     public Fluent AnyInt()
     {
         this._value += "42";
         return this;
     }
     public override string ToString() { return _value; }
}
```

You could also define an implicit or explicit conversion from `Fluent` to string, rather than (or in addition to) the `ToString()` override.

Also, for production code, I'd use a string builder to avoid many calls to `Concat`.

Comment: String builder append? What would an implicit conversion look like to get the result out? Is this thread safe also?

Comment: `public static implicit operator string(Fluent f) { return f.ToString(); }`. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z5z9kes2.aspx

Comment: @Jon, Unless you plan to use the same instance from multiple threads, thread-safety is not an issue you should worry about. Fluent interfaces is normally used in a single method, and then discarded.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to use + symbol. Use `StringBuilder` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder.aspx

**EXAMPLE**

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
builder.Append("One string ").Append("Second string").Append("Another string");
string final = builder.ToString();
```

If you want a simple custom FluentInterface  use the following:

```
public class MyOwnStringBuilder
{
   public StringBuilder Builder;


   public MyOwnStringBuilder()
   {
      this.Builder = new StringBuilder();
   }

   public static MyOwnStringBuilder Root
   {
     get{return new MyOwnStringBuilder();}
   }

   public string End
   {
     get{return Builder.ToString();}
   }

   public MyOwnStringBuilder And(string value)
   {
     Builder.Append(value);
     return this;
   }

   public MyOwnStringBuilder AnyInt(string value)
   {
      Builder.Append(value);
      return this;
   }
}
```

You would use it:

```
MyOwnStringBuilder.Root
       .And("some value")
       .AnyInt("some new value")
       .End;
```

Regards.

Comment: You would always need to call end though? Also this is for a web app so is it thread safe. Not sure how statics work for thread safety

Comment: Nice answer; I'd rename the class however :-)

Comment: yes you should call End, and there is not issues with thread safety. @phoog i named it after the proposed one in the question, but yes it would be better to rename it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I don't like having to call End every time though. I guess not much choice though

Comment: End() it so after N chains you tell the class to return the value. For such simple fluentinterfaces as this it's a best practice approach to have Root() or Start() and End(). Look at StringBuilder, you can chain  until you call ToString() which is basically a End() call. Accept as answer as i provided everything you wanted.

Comment: You could overload + in a custom class too, but that's probably overkill