# How to I chain methods from a list so that the result from one becomes the input of the next?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a list of processor objects that contain an execute method.  Now I want to execute each processor.Execute() in order from the List, but want the result from one to become the input to the next and so on until the last one in the list becomes the final result.

My code is like this

```
    private IDocument Execute(IDocument document, List<IProcessor> processors)
    {
        IDocument result = document;
        foreach (IProcessor p in processors)
        {
            result = p.Execute(document);
        }

        //return result;
    }
```

I don't know ahead of time how many processors there are in the list, but they are all the same (I.e. method signatures for the execute methods are all the same)

Comment: Might be some help here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10157982/designing-fluent-interface-methods

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume you want to feed in the updated `result` variable as input:

```
private IDocument Execute(IDocument document, List<IProcessor> processors)
{
    IDocument result = document;
    foreach (IProcessor p in processors)
    {
        result = p.Execute(result);
    }                      // ^ here

    return result;
}
```

You can express your method more concisely using LINQ:

```
private IDocument Execute(IDocument document, List<IProcessor> processors)
{
    return processors.Aggregate(document, (res, proc) => proc.Execute(res));
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I choose this because you also provided an alternative using LINQ.  I can't believe it was so simple. :)

Answer (score 2):

Simple. Instead of passing the original `document` to each processor, pass the `result` (which is the result from the previous processor). The result from *that* processor then becomes the next input for the next processor, and so on.

```
IDocument result = document;
foreach (IProcessor p in processors)
{
    result = p.Execute(result);
}
```